# 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Del diccionario

```
dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", "AMZN":"Amazon"}
```

Extraigo la lista

```
ticker_list = dicc_tickers.keys()
ticker_list
```

Salida:

```
dict_keys(['IBE.MC', 'TEF.MC', 'R4.MC', '^IBEX', '^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^N225', '^DJI', '^STOXX50E', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AMZN'])
```

Con el script siguiente, aplicándole ésta lista, importo las cotizaciones de todos los valores incluidos en ella.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

# Define the ticker list
tickers_list = ['IBE.MC', 'TEF.MC', 'R4.MC', '^IBEX', '^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^N225', '^DJI', '^STOXX50E', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AMZN']
# Download the data for the above tickers and extract the Adj Close column
price_data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2019-01-02")['Adj Close']
# Set the index to a datetime object
price_data.index = pd.to_datetime(price_data.index)

# Display the first 5 rows
price_data.head()
```

[image: DataFrame]

Si lo intento utilizando directamente el diccionario para obtener esta lista, me da el error mencionado en el título.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", "AMZN":"Amazon"}

# Define the ticker list
tickers_list = dicc_tickers.keys()
# Download the data for the above tickers and extract the Adj Close column
price_data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2019-01-02")['Adj Close']

# Set the index to a datetime object
price_data.index = pd.to_datetime(price_data.index)

# Display the first 5 rows
price_data.head()
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3102/3050173474.py in 
10 tickers_list = dicc_tickers.keys()
11 # Download the data for the above tickers and extract the Adj Close column
---> 12 price_data = yf.download(tickers_list, start="2019-01-02")['Adj Close']
13
14 # Set the index to a datetime object

```
~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py in download(tickers, start, end, actions, threads, group_by, auto_adjust, back_adjust, progress, period, show_errors, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding, timeout, **kwargs)
     74     # create ticker list
     75     tickers = tickers if isinstance(
---> 76         tickers, (list, set, tuple)) else tickers.replace(',', ' ').split()
     77 
     78     # accept isin as ticker

AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: `dicc_tickers.keys()` no es un diccionario; sólo son sus llaves.

Comment: Viendo la línea en el modulo `yfinance` que causa el error, parece que si no le pasas una lista, un conjunto o una tupla, asume que lo que le pasaste es una cadena. Pero es un `dict_keys` (un objeto que representa las llaves del diccionario). La solución es convertir el resultado de `dicc_tickers.keys()` a tupla, lista o conjunto con los respectivos constructores `tuple`, `list` y `set`. Ejemplo:  `list(dicc_tickers.keys())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es porque al definir la lista, como lo haces en tu primer ejemplo

```
tickers_list = ['IBE.MC', 'TEF.MC', 'R4.MC', '^IBEX', '^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^N225', '^DJI', '^STOXX50E', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AMZN']
```

`tickers_list` es en realidad una lista

Pero al hacer esto `tickers_list = dicc_tickers.keys()` entonces `tickers_list` es un objeto de tipo `dict_keys`

Puedes convertir ese objeto de tipo `dict_keys` a lista si utilizas `list(dicc_tickers.keys())`

Te quedaría así

```
tickers_list = list(dicc_tickers.keys())
```

De esa forma `tickers_list` será una lista y podrás utilizarla como en tu primer ejemplo